# MySQL Delete Rows With Duplicate and Similar Content

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I am new for PHP and MYSQL. In my study I met a problem

I have a table like this:

```
+----+----------+---------+
| time | name   | number  |
+----+----------+---------+
| 12.1 | google | 10      |
| 12.2 | yahoo  | 15      |
| 12.3 | msn    | 20      |
| 12.1 | google | 10      |
| 12.1 | google | 29      |
| 12.2 | yahoo  | 10      |
+----+----------+---------+
```

but I want the talbe like this:

```
+----+----------+---------+
| time | name   | number  |
+----+----------+---------+
| 12.2 | yahoo  | 15      |
| 12.3 | msn    | 20      |
| 12.1 | google | 29      |
+----+----------+---------+
```

when the time and the name are the same, I want the row with the max number,

what should I do? I am very worrying about this problem and thank you for anwsing me

Comment: Where's your code to do that? We can help you with your code, but we can't write it for you

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: but this can't return the one with max number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TRY ( not tested )

```
SELECT `time`, `name`, `number`
FROM tbl
GROUP BY `name`,`time`
HAVING MAX(`number`)
```

tip : **TIME** is a mysql reserve keyword so wrap it with `` ` `` and create Index on `name` and `time` column together

Comment: Excellent solution. I had tried it and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much. now I think I can continue my work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
 Select time, name, number from [table name] group by time, name having max(number)
```